# Maven generate Installer

Tags: maven, windows-installer, registry

I am currently working on a java project and i want to generate an installer which can add the program to the windows context menu automatically with maven. I had no luck with the generators i tried, some of them couldn't create windows registry entries (which are needed for the context menu), others were not free (it is only a side project so i don't want to spend money). I am already able to generate a .exe file with all dependencies wrapped inside, so i only need to generate an installer that copies this file to a user specified location, create some config/log folders in appdata (which can also be done by the application on first run) and create some registry entries to enable the context menu. I know java is not the language that installers are used most for, but maybe somebody had a similar use case and can provide some maven plugin that will generate the installer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A **recent answer** that might be relevant: [**MSI Installation Tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343445/wrap-c-sharp-application-in-msi-installer/50348142#50348142).

Comment: if you don't need to generate the MSI programmatically there's always the free AppDeploy repackager too (ok for simple captures like yours - a bit more cumbersome for complex captures): https://www.itninja.com/community/dell-kace-appdeploy-repackager

Comment: Write the configuration files needed by the tool you choose and invoke it from Maven.