# one installer for 3 programs

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to run one installer for three programs, i.e. Folder is created under the name KAM Package, and there are three separate folders with three separate programs and their files. They must also be separately in the start menu.

Comment: And I would like a pony. Luckily, you can get what you want by authoring an installer. I, on the other hand, will sadly never get a pony. Kidding aside, yes you can do this, but what is your question? What you describe is possible, but no one is going to tell you how when there are much better resources elsewhere.

Comment: You need to clarify. You can use InnoSetup, or you can tag as Windows Installer, but you cannot use both tags because InnoSetup is not a Windows Installer setup. Decide which tool suits your needs for a setup, and that would be any available install tool. Then ask specific questions.

Comment: I was talking about the .iss code for Inno Setup. I do not know anything about .iss, so I am asking for the code.

Comment: `*.iss` files can be (at least) `Installshield silent response files` as well as `Inno setup project files`. What is the situation, did you find an `*.iss` project file that you need to deal with?

Comment: No. I want to do it in the inno-setup

Answer (score 0):

***Welcome to Stackoverflow***: Please try to elaborate your questions and make them as specific as possible so we don't end up writing stuff that doesn't help or answer anything of what you really intended to ask about (happens more often than we'd like).

***Deployment Tools***: As others have said, **please choose a deployment tool first**. I'll just link to a previous answer to see if it helps you: **[How to create windows installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624070/how-to-create-windows-installer/49632260#49632260)** (links to Windows Installer tools and legacy setup tools - please do have a look).

***Free MSI Tools***: And there are free tools you can use to inspect compiled MSI files: [Orca, InstEd or SuperOrca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546) (towards bottom). These are not full-fledged tools to create MSI files, but they work great as viewers and for small hotfixes and changes, etc...

---

***Some Links***:

- [Wrap C# application in .msi installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343445/wrap-c-sharp-application-in-msi-installer/50348142#50348142)
- [Windows service NOT shown in add remove programs under control panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840)
- [What installation product to use? InstallShield, WiX, Wise, Advanced Installer, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544292/what-installation-product-to-use-installshield-wix-wise-advanced-installer/1546941#1546941)