# Add third party SDK in prerequisites of WPF Setup Project

Tags: c#, wpf, installation, setup-project

I am develop a WPF application,and created a set up project. In application , using  two third party SDK. I want also to install these two third party SDK, When the user install 'setup.exe'. Is there any options in setup prerequisites ?

Comment: which software do you use to make installer or exe file

Comment: followed https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/create-setup-and-deployment-of-wpf-application-step-by-step/

Comment: i think you should use wix toolset to create exe file. visual studio 2015 setup file is also made with wix toolset. here is a starting tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wyUxQux7xY

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50972797/additional-setup-in-visual-studio-installer-projects