# Add folder in C:\\ with Microsoft Visual Studio Installer

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-installer

I have created a program that needs to have DLLs in the C:\ folder. I have also created an installer using "Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects", but I would like it to create the folder C:\Subfolder with its files when it installs.

How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: A very delayed "answer" below.

Comment: Don't do this. It's very poor practice. Standard privileged users haven't had write access to the root C:\ folder or even Program Files folders since Windows 2000. **THERE ARE BETTER PLACES TO PUT YOUR DLLS!**

Comment: Yes, have to agree. In fact a software that installs files directly to a folder on the **C:** drive will very likely never be approved for distribution on the company network. These issues have become much more restrictive over the years. Standards that don't harm anything should be followed. Can we ask what the concrete details are?

Comment: [Long rant on the issue of root-folder installations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56304840/how-to-compress-multiple-files-and-directories-with-wix-installer-and-copy-and-i/56305728#56305728) :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MSI / Windows Installer to install your package, then installing directly to **`C:\`** is intentionally made difficult. There are almost no valid reasons to install directly to **`C:\`**. If at all possible install your application to **Program Files** (64 bit files) or **Program Files (x86)** (32-bit files) on your system drive. There are ways to force an MSI to install directly to **`C:\`**, but no good ways. [A long rant about it here (and how to do it with WiX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56304840/how-to-compress-multiple-files-and-directories-with-wix-installer-and-copy-and-i/56305728#56305728).

"*`Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects`*" are [**rather limited**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936435/visual-studio-publish-project-into-one-simple-installer/47944893#47944893), there are many alternative tools you can use. Some are free, some are commercial, and some of the commercial ones feature some free functionality:

- [List view of commonly used deployment tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840)
- [How to create windows installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624070/how-to-create-windows-installer/49632260#49632260) (top links show just about all tools available)
- [What installation product to use? InstallShield, WiX, Wise, Advanced Installer, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544292/what-installation-product-to-use-installshield-wix-wise-advanced-installer/1546941#1546941)

---

***Some Additional Links***:

- [Additional Setup in Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50972797/additional-setup-in-visual-studio-installer-projects/50976968#50976968)
- [How do Installation Software Programs Extract Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775173/how-do-installation-software-programs-extract-files/50779167#50779167)