# How to create a MSI file which simply copies a directory to Program Files?

Tags: windows-installer

I want to create a MSI file, which simply copies a directory into the "Program Files" directory and creates an icon in the start menu.

Nothing more.
No questions to the user, no dependencies, no registry entries, etc.
Just copy the directory and set the icon.

And if we deploy a new version of our program, then the MSI should just copy the new one over the old one. No "uninstalling" procedure.

Which tool to use for this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the answer is any common tool, since they can all do this. [**Here is a list of (arguably) the most common tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840).

- The **[Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)** (2017) are pretty simple to use - at first - and then you face [a number of limitations and shortcomings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130) that you might not be susceptible to - given your scope. **Can not be automated in a build process as far as I know!**
- **[Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com)** is a commercial product and it has [**`some free features`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50344650/129130) that you can use for requirements such as yours. You could give it a test spin. [**`Here is a great gateway`**](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=29130) to all things Advanced Installer.
- **[WiX](http://www.wixtoolset.org)** is capable of what you want to do, and entirely free. Takes a while to get used to. [The Hello World of WiX](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/105638/A-quick-introduction-Create-an-MSI-installer-with) (a little old and dated, but you get the picture - XML markup that is compiled to MSI format). For some reason, [this messy answer of mine on WiX Quick Start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130) has been upvoted more than usual (answer updated now - was small). Maybe skim it.

See linked answer on top for direct download links.

---

***Silent Install***: Any MSI file can be run silently (without a GUI) by means of a standard **`msiexec.exe`** command line:

```
msiexec.exe /I "C:\Your.msi" /QN /L*V "C:\msilog.log"
```

*Quick Parameter Explanation*:

```
/I = run install sequence
/QN = run completely silently
/L*V "C:\msilog.log" = verbose logging at specified path
```

Comment: The [WiX Toolset Tutorial](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/) is a good resource for getting started with WiX.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comprehensive answer! I'm currently having a look on all the tools mentioned by you and the other answer!

Comment: Finally the ADVANCED INSTALLER (even the freeware edition!) did the job! Thanks! It works like a charm, exactly what I wanted. I also tried WiX, but this is much too complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Just to extend on Stein's answer, with the [free edition](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html)(*"Simple" projects only*) of Advanced Installer you can build this simple package.

After you create the project just go to **Product Details** page and disable the option that says "*Register with Windows Installer*".

Most likely all of the tools mentioned above have a similar option, you just need to search it as I am not that familiar with all their ins and outs (*P.S. I work on the team building Advanced Installer*).

Comment: I am not sure he wants to disable Windows Installer registration, but maybe he does? I thought he said he had no actual registry entries of his own. But perhaps this no-registration approach is better for his simple requirements? If not, he needs to set up a basic major upgrade - and by the looks of it this happens auto-magically in the simple project type?

Comment: Well, that is what I understood by "simply copying" and "no uninstalling", and I've seen this request before from our users. Regarding the auto-upgrade, yes, it happens "auto-magically" in all project types, the user just needs to increase the version in Product Details page.

Comment: Yes, maybe that is what he needs. It looks like he wants to suppress the GUI as well though - now that I read it again. I will add a quick hint on how to suppress it. Tried that version update. Quite neat. Does the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this tool, too! Disabling "Register with Windows Installer" is something which I even didn't think of. @SteinÅsmul We have a .net cleint which connects to sql server. User configuration is stored in the database. The desktop environment, connection strings and .net libraries is the same on all computers, so we want it as simple as possible - just copy the client files to "Program Files" and that's it.

Comment: Just installing in silent mode with a simple MSI should be all you need then I think.